# Azure AD authenticated account DefaultNetworkCredentials is blank

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to obtain a SAML Assertion from Azure AD by hitting `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenetID}}/saml2?SAMLRequest=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

I've got browser based SSO working just fine, but have a need to obtain the actual SAML assertion itself to try and seamlessly obtain short lived AWS credentials for command line utilities.

The issue I'm finding is `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` doesn't return anything like it would if I was on an on-prem Active Directory setup. Is integrated authentication like this not supported without a hybrid setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting in touch with MS support, it seems integrated windows authentication is not supported with azure ad unless you are federating access via an on-prem AD server.